# How to make a information image

Tags: c#, winforms, border, picturebox

I am working on a program that i want to have a information image that when you mouse over it, a `ToolTip` shows up, what my problem is is that the `PictureBox` that has the information image on it has a border like this:

[image: PictureBox Border]

Does anyone know how to make the border on the `PictureBox` go away?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code that's being generated for this picture box?

Comment: Sorry, i am using WinForms.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi, are winforms.
this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290601/how-to-change-the-border-color-of-a-picturebox-winform

Comment: Oh sorry... didn't see the tag! :D

Comment: No, i added the TAG after your question, i always forget to do that.

Comment: Ahhh now it's explained why I missed the tag... :) I'm always with web development in mind anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can simply do this:

```
picture.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

Comment: The border in my picture is set at `BorderStyle.None`

Comment: And it still has that border.

Comment: YES! it worked, i had to add it to the code, i still don't know why it doesn't work in the properties. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It might be a bug in Visual Studio designer not applying the property when it is just set in the property grid.

Comment: At least you fixed my problem.